# Overflow:hidden property not working Jquery vertical slider on iphone, ipad

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css

I have to prototype a bulb shape (even an ellipse would be fine) vertical slider. The problem is that when I drag the slider it grows in rectangular manner and thus, doesn't take the elliptical shape (as it's parent element) on iphone and ipad. I have been able to add touch gestures but the property overflow:hidden doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Give your slider container border-radius, than add overflow: hidden to it. It works on iOS and Android:

```
.container {
width: 100%; /* Your slider width, percent or pixels... */
height: 100%; /* Your slider height*/
border-radius: 100%; /* Circle or ellipse, depends of parent element */
overflow: hidden; /* Crop content to border */
background: yellow; /* Irrelevant */
position: relative; /* Takes control of inner elements, could be irrelevant too */
}
```

Everything inside it will be cropped to border.